# How to copy block definition in autocad?

Tags: copy, block, definition, autocad

I need to copy block definition (not block reference) and set to copy other name in autocad 2022 within one drawing. How can I do that?

Comment: You want to do it in GUI or API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of my existing [Copy Block Definition](http://lee-mac.com/copyblockdefinition.html) function for this purpose.

Since it's not possible to have two block definitions with the same name in the same drawing, this function will copy the source block definition to the Blocks Collection within a new ObjectDBX Document, rename the copied block definition to the supplied target name, and then copy the renamed definition back to the Blocks Collection within the source drawing.